# Prime sequence with $\log n$ gap.

Tags: number-theory

How can we show that there is exist $\{p_{n}\} - $ sequence of neighbour-prime numbers with $p_{n+1} - p_{n} \ge C \log{n}$?

I don't want to use some famous estimates, may be there is exist idea only with Asymptotic law?

Comment: Yes, but $N << \ln{\pi(n)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to prove the easy version of the claim, ie: there exists some $C > 0$ such that there is an infinite sequence $\varphi(n)$ of integers such that $p_{\varphi(n)+1}-p_{\varphi(n)} \geq C \ln{\varphi(n)}$.

If it weren’t possible, then $p_{n+1}-p_n=o(\ln{n})$. But this implies $p_n=o(n\ln{n})$, a contradiction to the prime number theorem (or any “elementary” Chebyshev estimate).

I am unsure about the harder claim, ie $p_{n+1}-p_n \neq O(\ln{n})$.

Comment: What about first scenario ?

Comment: What do you mean, first scenario? How to prove or disprove that $p_{n+1}-p_n=O(\ln{n})$?

Comment: about $p_{\phi (n)+1} - p_{\phi(n)} \ge C \log \phi(n)$

Comment: I show in the answer that if there is no subsequence for any positive constant $C$, then $p_{k+1}-p_k=o(\ln{k})$, and therefore $p_k=o(k\ln{k})$ which is impossible. So there must exist such a sequence. For a practical realization, I suggest considering the prime gaps around the $\mu_n=lcm(1,\ldots,n)$. You can show $\ln{\mu_n}=\Theta(n)$.

Comment: oh, I understand! Thanks.